# Drop down extension button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a div that slides out on button click, then retracts when the button is clicked again.

Tested and the issue is with my JavaScript code, please see below.

```css
#containerExtension {
    height:0px;
    overflow: hidden
}

#containerExtension.show {
    height:auto;
}
```

```js
var extension = document.querySelector("#containerExtension");
var extensionButton = document.querySelector("#extensionButton");

extensionButton.addEventListener("click", showHide, false);

function showHide(){
    if(extension.classList.contains("show"){
        extension.classList.remove("show");
    }else{
        extension.classList.add("show");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is incorrect with my java, as it does not run. im assuming it is the was extension.classList.contains("show") line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the following document (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then modify your question accordingly.  Essentially, please be more specific in your question.  We are not a full-service debugging service.  "It does not run" does not tell us anything.  What did you expect to happen, and why. What actually happened?  What do you suspect is the culprit.  What research have you taken to try debugging the problem yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `)` in the conditional within your `showHide()` function. Should be:

```
function showHide(){
    if(extension.classList.contains("show")){
        extension.classList.remove("show");
    }else{
        extension.classList.add("show");
    }
}
```